# Understanding Support Verctor Regression (SVR)

Tags: python, svm, svr

**This question also asked on another StackExchange with  Bounty. [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137097/understanding-support-verctor-regression-svr).**

I'm working with SVR, and using this [resource](http://kernelsvm.tripod.com/). Erverything is super clear, with epsilon intensive loss function (from figure). Prediction comes with tube, to cover most training sample, and generalize bounds, using support vectors.

[image]

[image]

Then we have this explanation.  `This can be described by introducing (non-negative) slack variables , to measure the deviation of training samples outside -insensitive zone.` I understand this error, outside tube, but don't know, how we can use this in optimization. **Could somebody explain this?**

[image]

[image]

---

In local source. I'm trying to achieve very simple optimization solution, without libraries. This what I have for loss function.

```
import numpy as np

# Kernel func, linear by default
def hypothesis(x, weight, k=None):
    k = k if k else lambda z : z
    k_x = np.vectorize(k)(x)
    return np.dot(k_x, np.transpose(weight))

.......

import math

def boundary_loss(x, y, weight, epsilon):
    prediction = hypothesis(x, weight)

    scatter = np.absolute(
        np.transpose(y) - prediction)
    bound = lambda z: z \
        if z >= epsilon else 0

    return np.sum(np.vectorize(bound)(scatter))
```